# Why should arithmetic operators be padded by space in expr?

Tags: linux, bash, syntax, expr

Using `expr` to evaluate an expression in bash, the following happened

```
bash-3.2$ expr 1+1
1+1
bash-3.2$ expr 1 + 1
2
```

Why should the plus sign be padded by space for it to be interpreted as mathematical operation?

Comment: From the documentation `Each token of the expression must be a separate argument.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this has little to do with bash. From the man page of expr :

> All operators and operands must be passed as separate arguments

In order for operands and operators to be interpreted as separate arguments, You have to separate them (with a space).